# Laravel 5.2 return no response as JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, return, echo

If i try to return a JSON-String by using `return response()->json($categorie);` i get an empty response.
If i replace the `return` for `echo`, so i will get 
`HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json {"id":5,"name":"blah","parent":4,"visible":"yes","position":0,"created_at":"2016-06-29 15:23:25","updated_at":"2016-06-29 15:23:25"}` as Browser output.

I'm using Laravel 5.2.
Here's the complete code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Categories;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public static function categorieGetById($id) {
        $categorie = Categories::find($id);
        echo response()->json($categorie);
        // return response()->json($categorie);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: the controller returns nothing. every `return` produce an empty output. 
why?

Comment: `Categories::find($id)->toJson()` try it like so

Comment: Same result. `return` ist empty and `echo` passes the header to the output.

Comment: please, provide your JS code, may be its type missmatch in it. Do you have `dataType: 'json' //if its jquery for sure` at least?

Comment: What about `response($categorie);` and using `Accept: application/json` in client?

Comment: Can't you just `return $categorie;` and get proper JSON result? I think this is a Laravel feature for a long time.

Comment: UPDATE: the controller returns nothing. every `return` produce an empty output. why?

Comment: same problem for me. Did you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**toJson()**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses) method.

```
$categorie = Categories::find($id)->toJson();
echo $categorie;  // your json output
return $categorie; // same json output
```

> The toJson method converts the collection into JSON.

in your current code,

```
$categorie = Categories::find($id);
return response()->json($categorie);  // your json output with return
```

**Note**:- You must write `return` here.

In above code if you write **echo**,

```
echo response()->json($categorie);
```

then it will show

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json {"id":5,"name":"blah","parent":4,"visible":"yes","position":0,"created_at":"2016-06-29 15:23:25","updated_at":"2016-06-29 15:23:25"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A qoute from http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/return-json-response:

> In the official docs : http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses, need to do Response::json(...) to create json response. Actually, if the returned value is an array or instance of arrayableinterface or jsonableinterface such as eloquent model, you could just return it, it'll be a json, magically.